# Problem of using ajax call at the same time

Tags: javascript, ajax

Now, I have a problem with the ajax call which is when the web page is loaded, in the onload event of body, I assign it to call the functions which are `startCount()` and `updateTable()`  this two functions contain the code that use ajax call to get the data from DB on the server side. The problem is when the ajax return it will return only one call and another call does not response. Please help me what happen and how I can slove it.

This is the onload in the body

```
<body onLoad="setAjaxConnection();startCount();updateTable()">
```

I use the XMLHttpRequest with the normal javascript, I do not use jQuery....

Comment: My onload in the body is =====> onLoad="setAjaxConnection();startCount();updateTable()"

Comment: Can you add the code of the three functions as well?

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use jQuery?

Comment: Can you post the code inside the functions? Check you haven't got any global variables (e.g ensure your not declaring your `XMLHttpRequest` as a global variable, and overwriting it with the 2nd request).

Comment: Google for javascript closures and how to use them for multiple ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript closures. This link may help

http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/AJAX/How_do_I_handle_concurrent_AJAX_requests_.html

```
function AJAXInteraction(url, callback) {
    var req = init();
    req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function init() {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    }

    function processRequest () {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
          if (callback) callback(req.responseXML);
        }
      }
    }

    this.doGet = function() {
      req.open("GET", url, true);
      req.send(null);
    }

    this.doPost = function(body) {
      req.open("POST", url, true);
      req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      req.send(body);
    }
}

function startCount() {
  var ai = new AJAXInteraction("/path/to/count.php", function(){alert("After startCount");});
  ai.doGet();
}

function updateTable() {
  var ai = new AJAXInteraction("/path/to/update.php", function(){alert("After updateTable");});
  ai.doGet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the 'onSuccess' of one call initiate the next ajax call. So you would call `startCount()` and when that returns you fire off `updateTable()`.

Comment: This may "fix" the problem, but there is something more underlying than this; what you are trying *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setAjaxConnection(){
    //call Ajax here
    setAjaxConnectionResponce;
}

function setAjaxConnectionResponce(){
    //on readystate==4
    startCount();
}

function startCount(){
    // code for count
    updateTable();
}

function updateTable(){
    // code for update
}

<body onLoad="setAjaxConnection();">
```